# Is it possible to convert this numpy function to tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, implicit-conversion

I have a function that takes a [32, 32, 3] tensor, and outputs a [256,256,3] tensor.

Specifically, the function interprets the smaller array as if it was a .svg file, and 'renders' it to a 256x256 array as a canvas using [this algorithm](http://www.alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/)

For an explanation of WHY I would want to do this, see [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61862256/13564418)

The function behaves exactly as intended, until I try to include it in the training loop of a GAN.  The current error I'm seeing is:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (mul:0) to a numpy array.
```

A lot of other answers to similar errors seem to boil down to "You need to re-write the function using tensorflow, not numpy"

Here's the working code using numpy - is it **possible** to re-write it to exclusively use tensorflow functions?

```
def convert_to_bitmap(input_tensor, target, j):
    #implied conversion to nparray - the tensorflow docs seem to indicate this is okay, but the error is thrown here when training
    array = input_tensor
    outputArray = target
    output = target

    for i in range(32):
        col = float(array[i,0,j])
        if ((float(array[i,0,0]))+(float(array[i,0,1]))+(float(array[i,0,2]))/3)< 0:
            continue  

        #slice only the red channel from the i line, multiply by 255
        red_array = array[i,:,0]*255

        #slice only the green channel, multiply by 255
        green_array = array[i,:,1]*255

        #combine and flatten them
        combined_array = np.dstack((red_array, green_array)).flatten()

        #remove the first two and last two indices of the combined array
        index = [0,1,62,63]
        clipped_array = np.delete(combined_array,index)

        #filter array to remove values less than 0
        filtered = clipped_array > 0
        filtered_array = clipped_array[filtered]

        #check array has an even number of values, delete the last index if it doesn't
        if len(filtered_array) % 2 == 0: 
            pass
        else:
            filtered_array = np.delete(filtered_array,-1)

        #convert into a set of tuples
        l = filtered_array.tolist()
        t = list(zip(l, l[1:] + l[:1]))

        if not t:
            continue

        output = fill_polygon(t, outputArray, col)

    return(output)
```

The 'fill polygon' function is copied from the 'mahotas' library:

```
def fill_polygon(polygon, canvas, color):
if not len(polygon):
    return

min_y = min(int(y) for y,x in polygon)
max_y = max(int(y) for y,x in polygon)
polygon = [(float(y),float(x)) for y,x in polygon]

if max_y < canvas.shape[0]:
    max_y += 1 

for y in range(min_y, max_y):
    nodes = []
    j = -1
    for i,p in enumerate(polygon):
        pj = polygon[j]
        if p[0] < y and pj[0] >= y or pj[0] < y and p[0] >= y:
            dy = pj[0] - p[0]
            if dy:
                nodes.append( (p[1] + (y-p[0])/(pj[0]-p[0])*(pj[1]-p[1])) )
            elif p[0] == y:
                nodes.append(p[1])

        j = i

    nodes.sort()

    for n,nn in zip(nodes[::2],nodes[1::2]):
        nn += 1
        canvas[y, int(n):int(nn)] = color

return(canvas)
```

NOTE:  I'm not trying to get someone to convert the whole thing for me!  There are some functions that are pretty obvious (tf.stack instead of np.dstack), but others that I don't even know how to start, like the last few lines of the fill_polygon function above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can actually do this, you can use a python function in sth called `tf.pyfunc`. Its a python wrapper but its extremely slow in comparison to plain tensorflow. However, tensorflow and Cuda for example are so damn fast because they use stuff like `vectorization`, meaning you can rewrite a lot , really many of the loops in terms of mathematical tensor operations which are very fast.

***In general:***

If you want to use custom code as a custom layer, i would recommend you to rethink the algebra behind those loops and try to express them somehow different. If its just preprocessing before the training is going to start, you can use tensorflow but doing the same with numpy and other libraries is easier.

***To your main question:*** Yes its possible, but better dont use loops. Tensorflow has a build-in loop optimizer but then you have to use `tf.while()` and thats anyoing (maybe just for me). I just blinked over your code, but it looks like you should be able to vectorize it quite good using the standard tensorflow vocabulary. If you want it fast, i mean really fast with GPU support write all in tensorflow, but nothing like 50/50 with `tf.convert_to_tensor()`, because than its going to be slow again. because than you switch between GPU and CPU and plain Python interpreter and the tensorflow low level API. Hope i could help you at least a bit

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  After more investigation, it looks like my expansive question has reduced down to ‘how to vectorize the ‘point-in-polygon’ algorithm using only tensorflow functions’.  
I’ve come  a vectorized version of the point winding algorithm using numpy [here](https://community.esri.com/blogs/dan_patterson/2020/02/18/point-in-polygon-geometry-mysteries), but understanding it will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

This code 'works', in that it only uses tensorflow functions, and does allow the model to train when used in a training loop:

```
def convert_image (x):

    #split off the first column of the generator output, and store it for later (remove the 'colours' column)
colours_column = tf.slice(img_to_convert, tf.constant([0,0,0], dtype=tf.int32), tf.constant([32,1,3], dtype=tf.int32)) 

    #split off the rest of the data, only keeping R + G, and discarding B
image_data_red = tf.slice(img_to_convert, tf.constant([0,1,0], dtype=tf.int32), tf.constant([32,31,1], dtype=tf.int32))
image_data_green = tf.slice(img_to_convert, tf.constant([0,1,1], dtype=tf.int32), tf.constant([32, 31,1], dtype=tf.int32))

    #roll each row by 1 position, and make two more 2D tensors
rolled_red = tf.roll(image_data_red, shift=-1, axis=0)
rolled_green = tf.roll(image_data_green, shift=-1, axis=0)

    #remove all values where either the red OR green channels are 0
zeroes = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)

    #this is for the 'count_nonzero' command
boolean_red_data = tf.not_equal(image_data_red, zeroes)
boolean_green_data = tf.not_equal(image_data_green, zeroes)
initial_data_mask = tf.logical_and(boolean_red_data, boolean_green_data)

    #count non-zero values per row and flatten it
count = tf.math.count_nonzero(initial_data_mask, 1)
count_flat = tf.reshape(count, [-1])

flat_red = tf.reshape(image_data_red, [-1])
flat_green = tf.reshape(image_data_green, [-1])

boolean_red = tf.math.logical_not(tf.equal(flat_red, tf.zeros_like(flat_red)))
boolean_green = tf.math.logical_not(tf.equal(flat_green, tf.zeros_like(flat_red)))
mask = tf.logical_and(boolean_red, boolean_green)

flat_red_without_zero = tf.boolean_mask(flat_red, mask) 
flat_green_without_zero = tf.boolean_mask(flat_green, mask) 

    # create a ragged tensor
X0_ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(values=flat_red_without_zero, row_lengths=count_flat)
Y0_ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(values=flat_green_without_zero, row_lengths=count_flat)

    #do the same for the rolled version
rolled_data_mask = tf.roll(initial_data_mask, shift=-1, axis=1)

flat_rolled_red = tf.reshape(rolled_red, [-1])
flat_rolled_green = tf.reshape(rolled_green, [-1])


    #from SO "shift zeros to the end"
boolean_rolled_red = tf.math.logical_not(tf.equal(flat_rolled_red, tf.zeros_like(flat_rolled_red)))
boolean_rolled_green = tf.math.logical_not(tf.equal(flat_rolled_green, tf.zeros_like(flat_rolled_red)))
rolled_mask = tf.logical_and(boolean_rolled_red, boolean_rolled_green)

flat_rolled_red_without_zero = tf.boolean_mask(flat_rolled_red, rolled_mask) 
flat_rolled_green_without_zero = tf.boolean_mask(flat_rolled_green, rolled_mask) 

    # create a ragged tensor
X1_ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(values=flat_rolled_red_without_zero, row_lengths=count_flat)
Y1_ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(values=flat_rolled_green_without_zero, row_lengths=count_flat)

    #available outputs for future use are:
X0 = X0_ragged.to_tensor(default_value=0.)
Y0 = Y0_ragged.to_tensor(default_value=0.)
X1 = X1_ragged.to_tensor(default_value=0.)
Y1 = Y1_ragged.to_tensor(default_value=0.)

    #Example tensor cel (replace with (x))
P = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.float32)

    #split out P.x and P.y, and fill a ragged tensor to the same shape as Rx

Px_value = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.float32) - tf.cast((tf.math.floor(x/255)*255), dtype=tf.float32)
Py_value = tf.cast(tf.math.floor(x/255), dtype=tf.float32)

Px = tf.squeeze(tf.ones_like(X0)*Px_value)
Py = tf.squeeze(tf.ones_like(Y0)*Py_value)

    #for each pair of values (Y0, Y1, make a vector, and check to see if it crosses the y-value (Py) either up or down

a = tf.math.less(Y0, Py)
b = tf.math.greater_equal(Y1, Py)
c = tf.logical_and(a, b)

d = tf.math.greater_equal(Y0, Py)
e = tf.math.less(Y1, Py)
f = tf.logical_and(d, e)

g = tf.logical_or(c, f)

    #Makes boolean bitwise mask

    #calculate the intersection of the line with the y-value, assuming it intersects
    #P.x <= (G.x - R.x) * (P.y - R.y) / (G.y - R.y + R.x)   - use tf.divide_no_nan for safe divide

h = tf.math.less(Px,(tf.math.divide_no_nan(((X1-X0)*(Py-Y0)),(Y1-Y0+X0))))

    #combine using AND with the mask above

i = tf.logical_and(g,h)



    #tf.count_nonzero
    #reshape to make a column tensor with the same dimensions as the colours
    #divide by 2 using tf.floor_mod (returns remainder of division - any remainder means the value is odd, and hence the point is IN the polygon)


final_count = tf.cast((tf.math.count_nonzero(i, 1)), dtype=tf.int32)

twos = tf.ones_like(final_count, dtype=tf.int32)*tf.constant([2], dtype=tf.int32)

divide = tf.cast(tf.math.floormod(final_count, twos), dtype=tf.int32)

index = tf.cast(tf.range(0,32, delta=1), dtype=tf.int32)

clipped_index = divide*index

sort = tf.sort(clipped_index)

reverse = tf.reverse(sort, [-1])

value = tf.slice(reverse, [0], [1])

pair = tf.constant([0], dtype=tf.int32)

slice_tensor = tf.reshape(tf.stack([value, pair, pair], axis=0),[-1])

output_colour = tf.slice(colours_column, slice_tensor, [1,1,3])

return output_colour
```

This is where the 'convert image' function is applied using tf.vectorize_map:

```
def convert_images(image_to_convert):

global img_to_convert

img_to_convert = image_to_convert

process_list = tf.reshape((tf.range(0,65536, delta=1, dtype=tf.int32)), [65536, 1])

output_line = tf.vectorized_map(convert_image, process_list)

output_line_squeezed = tf.squeeze(output_line)

output_reshape = (tf.reshape(output_line_squeezed, [256,256,3])/127.5)-1

output = tf.expand_dims(output_reshape, axis=0)

return output
```

It is PAINFULLY slow, though - It does not appear to be using the GPU, and looks to be single threaded as well.

I'm adding it as an answer to my own question because is clearly IS possible to do this numpy function entirely in tensorflow - it just probably shouldn't be done like this.